# Check Groovy string if it matches dynamically changing substring

Tags: regex, string, groovy, substring, match

Here I have following Groovy-example looking for a match (product value) from the example text below.

```
def text = "This is my example text and it contains CD-12. Text continues after that."

def product = "CD-10"

if (text.contains("CD-12")) {
    println ("Match was found!")
}

else {
   println ("No match! Using default product " + product)
}
```

IF-block is executed as a direct match (CD-12) is found from the example text.

I have two additions that I have been investigating but so far have not succeeded.

**Addition 1, dynamically changing product in the text**

The first one is that let's imagine the number section for the `product` part `CD-XX` of text would change so that it would be anything between CD-1 - CD-99 (CD- remains not changing, only numbers following it would change) or that the part `CD-XX` would not exist at all in text.

If not existing then ELSE-block would be executed and default product printed (like my current ELSE-block) but otherwise the `product` variable would be replaced by matched value found from text (for example: CD-13).

I think there most likely is a regex way since it seems that contains does not allow regex?

**Addition 2, in case of multiple matches only take the latest one for product value**

If text was modified like this:

```
def text = "This is my example text and it contains CD-12. Text continues after that and here is also CD-15"
```

Then only the latest match (CD-15 in this case) would be taken as value for `product`.

**EDIT**: It seems like I got the first part (**Addition 1**) working like this:

```
def text = "This is my example text and it contains CD-12. Text continues after that. Text also contains CD-14"

def product = "CD-10"

// This line contains regex which looks for match from the text
def matches = text =~ "CD-\\d{1,2}"

println "Default product is: CD-10"

if (matches) {
    println "Match was found!"
    match = matches[0]
    println "Match is: " + match
    product = match
    println "Updated product is: " + match
}

else {
    println "No match"
    println "Product is the default value: " + product
}
```

In case of match this prints:

```
Default product is: CD-10
Match was found!
Match is: CD-12
Updated product is: CD-12
```

So as match was found from the text the default product got updated.
If CD-parts are removed from the text meaning no match, following gets printed:

```
Default product is: CD-10
No match
Product is the default value: CD-10
```

**Remaining challenge**:

What I am still looking for is how to only take the latest value in case of multiple matches (CD-14 as the latter in this updated example text).

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: Expected result would be to check if a product (CD-digit digit, for example CD-15) is found from text and if found, default value for product (CD-10 in example) replaced with that. If multiple matches found from text for example CD-15 and CD-18, only take the latest value, CD-18 and replace default value CD-10 with that. 

If no match found, use the default product value from ELSE-block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just take the last match - `[-1]` in groovy

```
def text =  "text contains CD-12. and continues with CD-15 after that."

def matches = (text =~ /CD-\w{1,2}/)
if(matches){
    println(matches[-1]) //print last
}else{
    println("not found")
}
```

this will print `CD-15`

Comment: Given the example `\d` might be better than `\w`